# Stuck in block mode

Tags: viking-battle-of-asgard

After coming back to Viking - Battle of Asgard after a break, I loaded my save game and my character is stuck in block mode. I cannot run, I cannot use Leystones or any other items in the world.

I already tried to die and got knocked off a cliff after a while, but after reviving my character is still stuck in block mode.

Is there any solution to this? I'm playing on the PC using Steam version.

Comment: If your question is about the Steam version, you should say so in your question, not with the Steam tag. The tag is for questions about the platform, not for questions about games on Steam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unplug your controller, start the game and load your save game. That should fix the issue.

Afterwards you can plug it in again and play it as before.